# Удалили Новогодний конкурс 2021 года!

Tags: обсуждение, соревнование

Что не так с ["Новогодний конкурс 2021 года!"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1225740/281034)? Eго взяли и удалили.

> Это сообщение скрыто. Оно было отмечено как спам или оскорбительный материал и удалено 4 минуты назад участниками Дух сообщества♦.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118227/discussion-on-question-by-tigertv-ru----2021-).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Просто спамер с 6 аккаунтов влепил тревоги спам, поэтому сообщение было удалено автоматически. Почистил тревоги и сообщение так же автоматически восстановилось.

Так же было несколько аналогичных тревог на ответах.

Все участвующие аккаунты забанены на год.

Comment: да, заработало.

Comment: Какие-то долгоживущие аккаунты были? Или однодневки?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ однодневки

Comment: интересно, а можно ли поменять такое поведение(удаление вопроса) если тревоги идут от временных аккаунтов? У них же карма маленькая обычно.

Comment: @Danis откуда инфа?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56686231#56686231

Comment: @Danis это всё косвенные признаки, к сожалению. Тут только модератор может подтвердить/опровергнуть

Comment: @αλεχολυτ тогда давайте спросим модератора

Comment: @Qwertiy это были однодневки, или нет?

Comment: @Danis, мне лень проверять, но он создаёт массово такие аккаунты относительно давно.

Comment: @Qwertiy просто если они однодневки, такие проблемы можно решать цензом оседлости и активности.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, так выставлено же - минимум 15 баллов для тревоги. Кроссголосованием можно любую репу накрутить, чтобы на тревогу хватило, так что повышать никакого смысла.

Comment: @Qwertiy значит, мало выставлено, имхо. Ну и баллы баллами, а срок их существования уже другое. Правда, вроде бы такого рода проверок вообще нигде нет. А так было бы доп.время накрутки сокпупетов проверить и откатить. Но, видимо, пока проблема не станет массовой - ничего делать не будут.