# Некорректная "проверка бдительности" в очереди проверок?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Проверяю очередь "Сообщения низкого качества". Натыкаюсь на следующее:

Вопрос:

> В чём разница между определением, объявлением, реализацией и инициализацией? ([В чём разница между определением, объявлением, реализацией и инициализацией?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/510523/344284?noredirect=1))

Ответ такого содержания (ниже поясню, почему без ссылки):

> Объявление переменной просто указывает тип данных переменной и имя
> переменной. В результате объявления мы говорим компилятору
> зарезервировать место для переменной в памяти в соответствии с
> указанным типом данных.
>
> Пример:
>
> ```cpp
> int result; 
> char c; 
> int a, b, c;
> ```
>
> Все вышеперечисленное является действительными декларациями. Также
> обратите внимание, что в результате объявления значение переменной не
> определено.
>
> Принимая во внимание, что определение - это реализация / создание
> объявленной переменной, в которой мы привязываем соответствующее
> значение к объявленной переменной, чтобы компоновщик мог связывать
> ссылки на соответствующие объекты.
>
> Из приведенного выше примера,
>
> ```cpp
> result = 10; 
> c = 'text';
> ```
>
> Это верные определения.

На мой взгляд (аргументируйте, если это не так), ответ довольно хороший, развёрнутый, понятный и правильный. Я сразу заподозрил, что данный ответ – проверка. **Проверка на то, отмечу ли я этот ответ, как качественный, нажав "Выглядит нормально"**, что я и сделал. Каково же было моё удивление, когда я увидел это:

> СТОП! Читайте и запоминайте.
>
> Данная проверка была нужна для того, чтобы оценить вашу
> внимательность. Вы не прошли проверку. В этом сообщении есть серьёзные
> недостатки, которые вряд ли можно исправить путём редактирования.
> Подобными недостатками могут быть оскорбления, спам, текст без смысла
> или не по теме. Подобные сообщения бесполезны, а порой даже вредны.
> Если при проверке вам попадаются такие, их нужно удалять и
> рекомендовать на удаление.
>
> Не волнуйтесь, мы уже позаботились об этом сообщении. Пожалуйста,
> уделите минуту и внимательно изучите его, учитывая вышеприведённые
> инструкции.
>
> Это сообщение скрыто. Оно было отмечено как спам или оскорбительный
> материал и удалено 6 дней назад участниками user7860670, Дух
> сообщества♦.

Сообщение стандартное для проваленной проверки, конечно, но меня удивило не само сообщение, а то, **где в этом ответе был найден "спам или оскорбительный материал"**. Это всё ещё вызывает моё недоумение.

Итак, вопрос: если кто-то понимает, почему так произошло и каким образом был удалён ответ, являющийся довольно качественным с моей точки зрения и уж точно не содержащий и близко ничего из описанного в причинах удаления, объясните, пожалуйста. Или же, если ответ был каким-то образом отредактирован после удаления (такое возможно?), то почему он попал в очередь проверок, да ещё и в качестве проверки моей бдительности?

Comment: Был задан вопрос от участника с репутацией 1,и дан ответ от участника с репутацией 1, и ответ был принят. После этого эти участники проголосовали за [Удаление новогоднего конкурса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11269/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9d%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81-2021-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0). Удалённый вопрос был восстанавлен, а вопрос и ответ от этих участников были помечены как Спам

Comment: и ещё автор этого ответа сейчас в бане https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/424386/guesswhat

Comment: Ответ не качественный, он как раз неправильный. Автор путает определение и инициализацию. Но удалять его как спам, просто потому что его автор насолил отдельным участникам, конечно ненормально.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight в последнее время кто-то создаёт аккаунты и начинает спамить под разными вопросами

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Это известный тролль. Все его посты должны быть уничтожены как спам. А вот в проверке это не честно согласен. Никак обычный проверяющий не определит, кто это.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor чтобы не генерировались плохие проверки, и не надо ставить отметку спама на все подряд. У модераторов же есть возможность удалить все сообщения от тролля без отметки спамом, пусть и удаляют. Сообщения с отрицательным рейтингом вообще должны автоматически удаляться при удалении аккаунта.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Charcoal — это в основном обычные участники, но они гораздо быстрее модераторов, именно благодарю этому механизму.

Comment: Коллеги, я немного не понимаю одну вещь. Раньше у нас считалось, что ответ необходимо оценивать лишь исходя из текста вопроса и текста ответа. Неужели сейчас это здесь более не так, и ответы от «плохого» человека заслуживают иной оценки, нежели ответы от «хорошего»? Я ранее всегда плюсовал хорошие ответы даже тех людей, которые мне лично неприятны.

Comment: @VladD Все остается так. За единственным исключением. Посты троллей должны быть уничтожены независимо от их контента. Мне это тоже не нравится, я пытался донести эту мысль, которую вы сейчас сказали, но... На самом деле от тролля гораздо больше вреда и снос всех их постов гораздо эффективнее. Т.к. конкретно вот этот тролль иногда пишет хорошие посты, но — с разнообразными плохими целями.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor: Мне крайне неприятна сама идея о том, пост человека, которого кто-то объявил «плохим», должен быть удалён не зависимо от контента, мне в этом видятся какие-то _костры из книг_. Несколько лет назад вот меня тоже местное руководство посчитало троллем, и банило за невинные фразы наподобие «Пфффф!». Я всё еще считаю, что удалять хорошие сообщения хоть от Гитлера — варварство уровня каменного века, и не подам руки тому, кто будет действовать в таком ключе.

Comment: @VladD Я согласен, но конкретно этот персонаж этого заслужил. Честно, я очевидец 99% его постов. И его "вопросы"/"ответы" плагиат были как всегда 99%. Модераторы enSO сказали CHQ сносить все посты этого человека. Нy я и сношу.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor: Да-да, и я тоже тогда, как считала администрация, заслужил. Модераторы сказали сносить не думая, это же они решили, а мы тут как бы не при чём, да?

Comment: @VladD Я не могу пуститься в подробности здесь т.к. мне в CHQ "давали по шапке" за это уже много раз ;) Но если я вам покажу его посты — вы согласитесь, что он это заслужил. Хотя мне лично это тоже не нравится... Но тут так все работает — и в конкретном случае все правильно.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor: Давайте я повторюсь. Я считаю, что на решение сносить пост или нет должно влиять лишь содержимое данного поста. Я считаю, что если Гитлер говорит, что дважды два — четыре, то он таки прав. Я считаю снос постов в отместку за что-либо (например, за другие посты) низким поступком. И мне всё равно, что считает руководство по этому поводу.

Comment: @VladD Мои просьбы не трогать полезные сообщения этого тролля в приватном тиме не дошли. И я получил кучу аргументов зачем сносить. Меня это не очень убедило, но тем не менее: тут все так работает.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor: Давайте вы мне не будете рассказывать, я был тут, когда ru.SO лишь начиналось, и я знаю, как, когда и что тут «работало». В качестве аналогии лишь скажу, что в уголовном кодексе за выполнение заведомо преступных приказов есть статья. Если мне говорят «можете делать гадость не думая, мы вам разрешаем», я, тем не менее, стараюсь гадости не делать. Потому что моя совесть для меня больший закон, чем местное руководство.

Comment: @VladD Я не знаю как тут все "работало" раньше, но сейчас полиси относительно троллей выглядит так.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor: Чья полиси? Ваша или кого-то, кто объявил себя имеющим право диктовать, как правильно поступать? Вы снова говорите «мне разрешили делать гадость, что ж, приходится.» Но никто вас не заставляет в реальности.

Comment: @VladD Модераторов и участников Charcoal.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor: Вот.

Comment: @VladD Предлагаю перевести дискуссию в зулип ;)

Answer (score 9):

Оба аккаунта (автора вопроса и автора ответа) созданы спамером с целью накрутки репутации на них, достаточной для получения возможности использовать тревогу "спам" на сообщениях нормальных участников и [уничтожения полезного контента](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/11269/178988). Помимо этого, данный человек даже не знает русский язык и сообщения являются либо машинным переводом, либо копипастом из другого места.

Единственный [ответ нормального участника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228774/178988) на этот вопрос перенесён в аналогичный вопрос путём объединения вопросов.

PS: Ссылка сейчас ведёт на целевой вопрос объединения, а не на удалённый.